# Flask exception handling: page not showing

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask web app. My app is prone to "HTTP too many requests error 429", so I want to handle that exception. After searching on the internet, I came up with this:

```
@app.errorhandler(TooManyRequests)
def handle_too_many_requests(e):
   return render_template('tooManyrequests.html')
```

I imported TooManyRequests like this:

```
from werkzeug.exceptions import TooManyRequests
```

When this error occurs, instead of showing 'tooManyRequests.html', my app still shows the stack tree saying that the error occured. How can I display the page I want instead of the default "Don't panic" that reveals all the code?

EDIT: Ok, so the "Don't panic" is gone now as I changed app.run(debug=True) to simply app.run(). However, although it doesn't display any code, it just shows a basic html page that says "Internal Server Error" when the exception occurs instead of showing my custom tooManyRequests.html

Answer (score -1):

It seems you are running you app in debug mode

You shouldhiuld run your app as this `app.run()`

Comment: I put app.run(debug = True), should I just do app.run()?

Comment: Ok I just did app.run() but it displays some default html "Internal Sever Error" page instead of showing the one I want to show.

Comment: Change the return to this render_template() ,429

Comment: Also, the render_template('tooManyrequests.html'), 429 doesn't seem to work

Comment: Also the flask devolopment server can't handle multiple requests at a time

Comment: It says "Internal Server Error" - it's the too many requests error, my app goes on many links and if you use it too much the http requests server will raise a "too many requests" error, but I want to show my custom page when this happens